# Pass an array to angular directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have this directive which sets focus on an input field when it appears and hides it when it loses focus or the esc/enter/tab key is pressed. It works just fine, but I wanted to know if there was a way I could pass in an array or object of keys (and event types) instead of hard coding the keys and events into the directive itself?
Here is the code:

```
.directive('bindKeys', function ($timeout) {

    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            trigger: '='
        },

        link: function(scope, elem){

            elem.bind('keydown keypress blur', function (event) {
                    if(event.which === 13 || event.which === 9 || event.which === 27 || event.type === 'blur') {
                        event.preventDefault();
                        $timeout(function(){
                            scope.trigger.property = false;
                        });
                    }
                });
            scope.$watch('trigger.property', function(value) {

                if(value === true) {
                    $timeout(function() {
                        elem[0].focus();
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    };
});
```

The element looks like this:

```
<input bindKeys trigger='trigger'></input>
```

Thanks

Comment: you could pass your config array as an attribute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You sure can. Have some module provide your array

```
.value('events', ['blur', 'keypress'])
```

And then have them inject into you directive (events var name must match key above).

```
.directive('bindKeys', function ($timeout, events) {
    // ...
    element.bind(events.join(' '), function() {})
}
```

The alternative syntax to inject your array is by explicitly defining names to vars

`.directive('bindKeys', ['$timeout', 'events', function ($timeout, events) {})`

See more on dependency injection here:
https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di

and on modules here:
https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module

Comment: Sorry it took so long to reply, but this was just what I was looking for.